# Will a php script wait if it wants to read from a locked table?

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency

I have a cli php script that is executed whenever an email arrives at a specific address.

When a new email arrives a new instance of the script is executed but because they read/write to the same DB tables sometimes wrong data is written.

My question is if the first script puts a lock on all the tables that it needs and a second/third etc instance of the script is run, will they wait for the tables to be unlocked by the first executed script? If so for how long?

In the end what I'm trying to do is make the scripts do their read/writes one after the other in a serial fashion so as to avoid duplication and errors.

Comment: you need to provide specific examples, also how your db is implemented and what exactly is written on db and how. also "wrong data is written" please define.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will wait. This is done by the database server, the client application is totally unaware that it's happening -- as far as it can tell, the database is just being slow to perform the query.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP script uses a mysql library (mysql, mysqli, pdo) that as any mysql client connects to the mysql server and has it execute a query. The mysql server can take all the time it wants.

But PHP can be set to have a total script execution time (with any mysql query included) to be limited. If this limit is exceeded, PHP will kill the running process. The max execution time is 30 seconds by default, and for cli even 300 seconds, if I'm not mistaking. You can set this in the php.ini. You can even set the CLI max execution time to unlimited.

Comment: Database queries are not included in the execution time, with the execption of windows operating systems. See the note on the manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php